# DirectX11: Почему после инициализации буфера глубины объект на экране не отображается?

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11, direct3d

Я в своей программе попробовал реализовать вращающийся куб с текстурой. Куб я лишь нарисовал с трёх сторон, но уже обнаружил проблему — после инициализации буфера глубины, ничего не станет отображаться на экране. Если вовсе убрать метод инициализации буфера глубины `InitDepthBuffer()`, которая вызывается в методе `InitD3D()`, то будет вращающийся куб, но *неправильно* отображённый.

Я проверил HRESULT всех методов в методе `InitDepthBuffer()`, но не обнаружил ошибки.

*My Game.cpp*

```
// include the basic windows header files and the Direct3D header files
#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <d3dx11.h>
#include <d3dx10.h>
#include <xnamath.h>

// include the Direct3D Library file
#pragma comment (lib, "d3d11.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "d3dx11.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "d3dx10.lib")

// define the screen resolution
#define SCREEN_WIDTH  800
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 600

// global declarations
IDXGISwapChain* swapchain;             // the pointer to the swap chain interface
ID3D11Device* dev;                     // the pointer to our Direct3D device interface
ID3D11DeviceContext* devcon;           // the pointer to our Direct3D device context
ID3D11RenderTargetView* backbuffer;    // the pointer to our back buffer
ID3D11InputLayout* pLayout;            // the pointer to the input layout
ID3D11VertexShader* pVS;               // the pointer to the vertex shader
ID3D11PixelShader* pPS;                // the pointer to the pixel shader
ID3D11Buffer* pVBuffer;                // the pointer to the vertex buffer
ID3D11Buffer* pIBuffer;
ID3D11Buffer* wvpConstBuffer;
ID3D11DepthStencilView* pDepthBuffer;
ID3D11Texture2D* depthStencilBuffer;
ID3D11ShaderResourceView* pTexture;    // the texture
ID3D11SamplerState* pSamplerState;
ID3D11RasterizerState* pRasterState;

// a struct to define a single vertex
struct VERTEX { FLOAT X, Y, Z, texX, texY; };

struct ConstantBuffer
{
    XMMATRIX mWorld;
    XMMATRIX mView;
    XMMATRIX mProjection;
};

XMMATRIX g_World;
XMMATRIX g_View;
XMMATRIX g_Projection;

// function prototypes
void InitD3D(HWND hWnd);    // sets up and initializes Direct3D
void RenderFrame(void);     // renders a single frame
void CleanD3D(void);        // closes Direct3D and releases memory
void InitGraphics(void);    // creates the shape to render
void InitPipeline(void);    // loads and prepares the shaders

// the WindowProc function prototype
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);


// the entry point for any Windows program
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine,
    int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND hWnd;
    WNDCLASSEX wc;

    ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));

    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.lpszClassName = L"WindowClass";

    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    RECT wr = { 0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT };
    AdjustWindowRect(&wr, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, FALSE);

    hWnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL,
        L"WindowClass",
        L"My Game",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        300,
        300,
        wr.right - wr.left,
        wr.bottom - wr.top,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL);

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);

    // set up and initialize Direct3D
    InitD3D(hWnd);

    // enter the main loop:

    MSG msg;

    while (TRUE)
    {
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);

            if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
                break;
        }

        RenderFrame();
    }

    // clean up DirectX and COM
    CleanD3D();

    return msg.wParam;
}


// this is the main message handler for the program
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    } break;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}

void InitDepthBuffer()
{
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC td;
    ZeroMemory(&td, sizeof(D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC));
    td.Width = SCREEN_WIDTH;
    td.Height = SCREEN_HEIGHT;
    td.MipLevels = 1;
    td.ArraySize = 1;
    td.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    td.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
    td.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL;

    dev->CreateTexture2D(&td, NULL, &depthStencilBuffer);

    D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC dsvDesc;
    ZeroMemory(&dsvDesc, sizeof(D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC));
    dsvDesc.Format = td.Format;
    dsvDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2DMS;
    dev->CreateDepthStencilView(depthStencilBuffer, &dsvDesc, &pDepthBuffer);
}

// this function initializes and prepares Direct3D for use
void InitD3D(HWND hWnd)
{
    // create a struct to hold information about the swap chain
    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC scd;

    // clear out the struct for use
    ZeroMemory(&scd, sizeof(DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC));

    // fill the swap chain description struct
    scd.BufferCount = 1;                                   // one back buffer
    scd.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;    // use 32-bit color
    scd.BufferDesc.Width = SCREEN_WIDTH;                   // set the back buffer width
    scd.BufferDesc.Height = SCREEN_HEIGHT;                 // set the back buffer height
    scd.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;     // how swap chain is to be used
    scd.OutputWindow = hWnd;                               // the window to be used
    scd.SampleDesc.Count = 4;                              // how many multisamples
    scd.Windowed = TRUE;                                   // windowed/full-screen mode
    scd.Flags = DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_ALLOW_MODE_SWITCH;    // allow full-screen switching

    // create a device, device context and swap chain using the information in the scd struct
    D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL,
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
        &scd,
        &swapchain,
        &dev,
        NULL,
        &devcon);


    // get the address of the back buffer
    ID3D11Texture2D* pBackBuffer;
    swapchain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (LPVOID*)&pBackBuffer);

    // use the back buffer address to create the render target
    dev->CreateRenderTargetView(pBackBuffer, NULL, &backbuffer);
    pBackBuffer->Release();

    InitDepthBuffer();
    // set the render target as the back buffer
    devcon->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &backbuffer, pDepthBuffer);

    // Set the viewport
    D3D11_VIEWPORT viewport;
    ZeroMemory(&viewport, sizeof(D3D11_VIEWPORT));

    viewport.TopLeftX = 0;
    viewport.TopLeftY = 0;
    viewport.Width = SCREEN_WIDTH;
    viewport.Height = SCREEN_HEIGHT;
    viewport.MinDepth = 0.0f;
    viewport.MaxDepth = 1.0f;

    devcon->RSSetViewports(1, &viewport);

    InitPipeline();
    InitGraphics();
}


// this is the function used to render a single frame
void RenderFrame(void)
{
    // update WVP matrices
    ConstantBuffer cb;
    cb.mWorld = XMMatrixTranspose(g_World);
    cb.mView = XMMatrixTranspose(g_View);
    cb.mProjection = XMMatrixTranspose(g_Projection);
    devcon->UpdateSubresource(wvpConstBuffer, 0, NULL, &cb, 0, 0);

    // clear the back buffer to a deep blue and the depth buffer
    devcon->ClearRenderTargetView(backbuffer, D3DXCOLOR(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
    devcon->ClearDepthStencilView(pDepthBuffer, D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH | D3D11_CLEAR_STENCIL, 1.0f, 0);

    // select which vertex buffer to display
    UINT stride = sizeof(VERTEX);
    UINT offset = 0;
    devcon->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &pVBuffer, &stride, &offset);
    devcon->IASetIndexBuffer(pIBuffer, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT, 0);
    devcon->VSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, &wvpConstBuffer);

    // select which primtive type we are using
    devcon->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D10_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);

    // draw the vertex buffer to the back buffer
    devcon->DrawIndexed(24, 0, 0);

    // switch the back buffer and the front buffer
    swapchain->Present(0, 0);

    g_World *= XMMatrixRotationY(XM_PI / 12);
    Sleep(100);
}


// this is the function that cleans up Direct3D and COM
void CleanD3D(void)
{
    swapchain->SetFullscreenState(FALSE, NULL);    // switch to windowed mode

    // close and release all existing COM objects
    pLayout->Release();
    pVS->Release();
    pPS->Release();
    pVBuffer->Release();
    swapchain->Release();
    backbuffer->Release();
    dev->Release();
    devcon->Release();
}

void InitTextures()
{
    D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile(dev, L"texture.png", NULL, NULL, &pTexture, NULL);

    D3D11_SAMPLER_DESC sampDesc;
    ZeroMemory(&sampDesc, sizeof(D3D11_SAMPLER_DESC));
    sampDesc.Filter = D3D11_FILTER_MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR;
    sampDesc.AddressU = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;
    sampDesc.AddressV = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;
    sampDesc.AddressW = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;
    sampDesc.ComparisonFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_NEVER;
    sampDesc.MinLOD = 0;
    sampDesc.MaxLOD = D3D11_FLOAT32_MAX;
    dev->CreateSamplerState(&sampDesc, &pSamplerState);
}

// this is the function that creates the shape to render
void InitGraphics()
{
    // create a triangle using the VERTEX struct
    VERTEX OurVertices[] =
    {                                       // CUBE
        {-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f},    // Front
        {0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f},
        {0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f},
        {-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f},
        
        {-0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f},    // Back
        {0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f},
        {0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f},
        {-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f},
    };

    // create the vertex buffer
    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bd;
    ZeroMemory(&bd, sizeof(bd));

    bd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;                // write access access by CPU and GPU
    bd.ByteWidth = sizeof(OurVertices);             // size is the VERTEX struct * 3
    bd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;       // use as a vertex buffer
    bd.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;    // allow CPU to write in buffer

    dev->CreateBuffer(&bd, NULL, &pVBuffer);       // create the buffer

    // copy the vertices into the buffer
    D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE ms;
    devcon->Map(pVBuffer, NULL, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, NULL, &ms);    // map the buffer
    memcpy(ms.pData, OurVertices, sizeof(OurVertices));                 // copy the data
    devcon->Unmap(pVBuffer, NULL);                                      // unmap the buffer

    unsigned int indices[] =
    {
        0, 1, 2, // front
        0, 2, 3,

        4, 0, 3, // left
        4, 3, 7,

        //4, 5, 6, // back
        //4, 6, 7,

        6, 5, 1, // right
        6, 1, 2,
    };

    // indices
    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bdIndices;
    bdIndices.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    bdIndices.ByteWidth = sizeof(indices);
    bdIndices.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER;
    bdIndices.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    bdIndices.MiscFlags = 0;
    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA InitData;
    InitData.pSysMem = indices;
    InitData.SysMemPitch = 0;
    InitData.SysMemSlicePitch = 0;
    dev->CreateBuffer(&bdIndices, &InitData, &pIBuffer);

    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bdWVP;
    ZeroMemory(&bdWVP, sizeof(D3D11_BUFFER_DESC));
    bdWVP.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    bdWVP.ByteWidth = sizeof(ConstantBuffer);
    bdWVP.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_CONSTANT_BUFFER;
    bdWVP.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    dev->CreateBuffer(&bdWVP, NULL, &wvpConstBuffer);

    g_World = XMMatrixIdentity();

    XMVECTOR Eye = XMVectorSet(0.0f, 1.0f, -3.0f, 0.0f);
    XMVECTOR At = XMVectorSet(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    XMVECTOR Up = XMVectorSet(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    g_View = XMMatrixLookAtLH(Eye, At, Up);

    g_Projection = XMMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(XM_PIDIV2, SCREEN_WIDTH / (FLOAT)SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0.01f, 100.0f);
}

void InitRasterizer()
{
    D3D11_RASTERIZER_DESC raster_desc;
    raster_desc.FillMode = D3D11_FILL_SOLID;
    raster_desc.CullMode = D3D11_CULL_NONE;
    raster_desc.FrontCounterClockwise = false;
    raster_desc.DepthBias = 0;
    raster_desc.DepthBiasClamp = 0.0f;
    raster_desc.SlopeScaledDepthBias = 0.0f;
    raster_desc.DepthClipEnable = true;
    raster_desc.ScissorEnable = false;
    raster_desc.MultisampleEnable = false;
    raster_desc.AntialiasedLineEnable = false;

    dev->CreateRasterizerState(&raster_desc, &pRasterState);
}

// this function loads and prepares the shaders
void InitPipeline()
{
    InitRasterizer();
    InitTextures();
    // load and compile the two shaders
    ID3D10Blob* VS, * PS;
    D3DX11CompileFromFile(L"shaders.shader", 0, 0, "VShader", "vs_4_0", 0, 0, 0, &VS, 0, 0);
    D3DX11CompileFromFile(L"shaders.shader", 0, 0, "PShader", "ps_4_0", 0, 0, 0, &PS, 0, 0);

    // encapsulate both shaders into shader objects
    dev->CreateVertexShader(VS->GetBufferPointer(), VS->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &pVS);
    dev->CreatePixelShader(PS->GetBufferPointer(), PS->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &pPS);

    // set the shader objects
    devcon->VSSetShader(pVS, 0, 0);
    devcon->PSSetShader(pPS, 0, 0);

    // set the texture
    devcon->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &pTexture);
    devcon->PSSetSamplers(0, 1, &pSamplerState);

    // off cull mode
    devcon->RSSetState(pRasterState);

    // create the input layout object
    D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC ied[] =
    {
        {"POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
        {"TEXCOORD", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT, 0, 12, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
    };

    dev->CreateInputLayout(ied, 2, VS->GetBufferPointer(), VS->GetBufferSize(), &pLayout);
    devcon->IASetInputLayout(pLayout);
}
```

*shaders.shader*

```
cbuffer ConstantBuffer : register(b0)
{
    matrix World;
    matrix View;
    matrix Projection;
}

Texture2D ObjTexture;
SamplerState ObjSamplerState;

struct VS_OUTPUT
{
    float4 Pos : SV_POSITION;
    float2 TexCoord : TEXCOORD;
};

VS_OUTPUT VShader(float4 Pos : POSITION, float4 inTexCoord : TEXCOORD)
{
    VS_OUTPUT output = (VS_OUTPUT)0;
    output.Pos = mul(Pos, World);
    output.Pos = mul(output.Pos, View);
    output.Pos = mul(output.Pos, Projection);
    output.TexCoord = inTexCoord;
    return output;
}

float4 PShader(VS_OUTPUT input) : SV_Target
{
    return ObjTexture.Sample(ObjSamplerState, input.TexCoord);
}
```

[image: Вращающийся куб, неправильно отображённый]

Comment: Ну во-первых для рисования куба надо 12 треугольников. А так на картинке рисуется как раз то, что нужно - три стороны без теста глубины. Причем количество индексов в вызове DrawIndexed указано больше, чем есть.

Comment: Там какой-то странный формат используется  D3D11_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2DMS когда текстура без мультисемплинга - тоже неверно. Еще не видно вызовов `CreateDepthStencilState` `OMSetDepthStencilState` - как тогда тест глубины будет использоваться?

Comment: Я всё делал по этому (https://www.braynzarsoft.net/viewtutorial/q16390-7-depth) руководству. А что 
нужно вместо D3D11_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2DMS поставить?

Comment: В том руководстве вторым аргументом в `CreateDepthStencilView` передается nullptr. Если не используется мультисемплинг, то D3D11_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D И еще вот https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/d3d10-graphics-programming-guide-depth-stencil

Comment: Сделал оба варианта, но всё осталось прежним. Дело в том, что я пробовал исправить проблему с разных источников, поэтому код немного отличается от кода из руководства.

Comment: Не заметил, но ничего не изменилось :( Зато хотя бы куб после вызова отображается.

Comment: Код на данный момент: https://pastebin.com/8YZy2z2S

Comment: И как куб отображается?

Comment: По моему ничего не изменилось. Так же.

Comment: Формат текстуры не соответствует DXGI_FORMAT_D32_FLOAT_S8X24_UINT

Comment: Я изменил на DXGI_FORMAT_D32_FLOAT_S8X24_UINT, не помогает.

Comment: Может глубина работает только для отдельных вызовов Draw? Здесь я использую лишь одну функцию Draw для рисования всех сторон куба. Может нужно все стороны куба по отдельности нарисовать (несколькими вызовами Draw)? Или это не имеет значения?

Comment: Нет конечно, рисовать можно сразу все. Более того, уже заполненный буфер глубины будет продолжать использоваться в последующих вызовах рисования. Попробуйте открыть графический отладчик и посмотреть, что там творится. Он показывает в истории пикселей, когда те не рисуются если проваливают тест глубины. Ну и состояние конвеера проще проверять, чем по коду глазами бегать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сегодня свежим взглядом я заметил, что помимо проблем, которые я упоминал ранее, render target view и depth stencil view используют разные настройки мультисемплинга: render target использует 4 семпла, а depth stencil только 1. Чтобы они могли работать вместе, их размеры и настройки мультисемплинга должны быть в точности одинаковыми.

Comment: Что я только не делал, чтобы найти проблему! Спасибо вам. Я поменял значение scd.SampleDesc.Count у цепочки обмена на 1 — это сработало.

Comment: Кстати, а почему, если у обеих указать SampleDesc.Count = 4, то это не будет работать, в отличие от 1. Получается, что когда используется сглаживание, то задний буфер не работает?

Comment: @Arkady Это должно работать.

Comment: Но это не работает. Может ли причиной быть то, что я использую текстуру? Ведь там изменяется какое-то состояние сэмплера. Или этот параметр для пиксельного шейдера (`PSSetSamplers`) не имеет значения на исход?

Comment: @Arkady Ну значит вы опять что-то не так делаете.

Comment: У меня ещё один вопрос немного не по теме. Скажите, я правильно понимаю, что после того, как вызывается один из методов рисования (Draw), то данный метод, рисует объект по заданными данными из конвейера, а затем ОБМНУЛЯЕТ ИХ. То есть устанавливает на 0 данные, заданные методами семейств `VSSetXxx` и `PSSetXxx`? Если моё предположение верно, то получается, все вершинные буферы, индексы вершин и т.д. заново нужно обязательно устанавливать перед следующим рисованием, верно?

Comment: @Arkady Ничего подобного не происходит, состояние само по себе не сбрасывается.

Comment: Получается методу, который рисует обычный цветной квадрат, перед каждым рисованием нужно лишь установить свой шейдер и лишь необходимые для работы шейдера данные (вершины, индексы) и запустить метод Draw? И остальные данные будут просто игнорироваться?

Comment: @Arkady Никакие данные игнорироваться не будут. Будет использоваться то состояние конвейера, которое было. Если нужный шейдер был выбран ранее, то выбирать его повторно нет необходимости. Также и с остальными элементами состояния конвеера.

Comment: То есть, например, установленная текстура (`PSSetSamplers`) будет передана в соответствующие переменные пиксельного шейдера, но не будет использована им, так?

Comment: @Arkady PSSetSamplers устанавливает не текстуру, а состояние семплера. Если в конвейере уже установлено несколько семплеров, то без вызова этой функции они все так и будут оставаться. Шейдер будет использовать семплер в том слоте, в котором он объявлен. Шейдер из вопроса использует семплер из слота 0, если там установлены еще семплеры в других слотах, то они не будут использоваться, а так и будут там сидеть.

Comment: вы говорили про то, что не нужно устанавливать нужный шейдер, когда он уже установлен. Нужно каждый раз перед рисованием проверять на наличие нужного шейдера, чтобы, я так понимаю, сэкономить процессорное время? Я просто пытаюсь понять основные моменты для создания гибкой графики.

Comment: @Arkady Ну вообще да, желательно реже менять состояние конвейра, меньше вызовов рисования, рисовать больше за один вызов, и т.п. Но вам наверное лучше пока разобраться с корректностью написания.

Comment: А если сторонние ненужные шейдеру данные, например, состояние семплера, постоянно загружаются в конвейер, это не будет влиять на производительность? Или, я так понимаю, шейдер будет загружать только те данные, которые нужны ему самому, а другие будет игнорировать.